# Configure Filebeat Shippers Programmatically

Tags: java, shell, filebeat

How do I programmatically create a Filebeat like shipper, which will ship my logs from client server to the remote logstash server.

I am new to ELK and log4j, i am trying  to create Daemonize java program or shell script which will keep reading my log file line by line and it will ship all lines (and any new ones) to the defined logstash server.

I am able to read the file line by line , but it closes as soon it reach EOF.

Moreover, i want to make it Daemonized process which will keep monitoring the log file and it will send each line to Logstash over TCP.

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

String strLine;
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {

  System.out.println (strLine);
}
br.close();
```

Can someone please guide me in the right direction ?

Comment: protip : **never** use assignments and comparisons in the heads of loops at the same time. Thats what most people call "bad code". Split it up and compare the value in the loop-head, everything else will lead to mistakes in programming, its what makes you think that pretty much everything which compiles is "good" practise - which isnt the case. Get used to "best practise", avoid mistakes at all costs and use a clear, concise, consistent programming paradigm - for instance : you should also **always** initialize your variables.

Comment: Thank you , Will make sure not use that, but this code is merely a right one for the task i want to achieve.

Comment: merely a ... what?

Answer (score 0):

Now,

Filebeat is really existing no programmation to do just use the beat package go to

https://www.elastic.co